# Is there a way to block on applying tasks in Python ThreadPool if all the threads in the pool are busy?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm consuming a queue and need to pass the data to a thread pool for processing, but I don't want to consume more items than the thread pool can handle. In other words, I want the thread pool to regulate the rate at which the queue is consumed.

With Python's default `ThreadPool`, the `apply_async()` function returns immediately and apparently the task queue for the thread pool can grow unbounded - exactly what I want to avoid. The `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s `submit()` function seems to do the same.

Is there a way to do it with the standard library or a third party module, or do I have to do it with regular threads pulling records from the queue?

Comment: You can limit the size of the thread pool

Comment: Do I get you right, that for example having `ThreadPoolExecutor(10)` and while all 10 threads are running and busy you want to block adding new thread? If so it looks like you would need to implement some custom semaphore and make a wrapper over Thread Pool which will utilize semaphore as a blocker to control adding new threads.

Comment: Exactly that. I was wondering if there's some existing module or option for that, to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control how many tasks can be either currently executing by a pool thread/process or sitting in the pool's input queue waiting to be executed by using a properly-initialized `threading.Semaphore` instance (if the pool size is N then my preference is to have all N pool processes executing a submitted task and to have an additional N tasks sitting in the pool's input queue immediately available to be run when a pool thread/process becomes idle without first having to wait for a new task to be submitted).

So if the pool size is 8, for example, we want to initialize the semaphore with a count of 16 or greater (again, this is my preference but you can set the value to any value N that allows a total of N tasks to either be currently executing or sitting in the input queue awaiting execution). The following code is using a multiprocessing pool but works equally well with a multithreading pool:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from threading import Semaphore

def generate_args() -> int:
    for arg in range(0, 1_000):
        yield arg

def worker(x: int) -> int:
    """Square the input."""

    return x * x

def main() -> None:
    results = []
    pool_size = cpu_count()
    # This allows for each pool process/thread to be running a task
    # and to have the input queue have a task for each process/thread
    # to immediately run when it becomes idle:
    semaphore = Semaphore(2 * pool_size)

    def callback(result: int) -> None:
        results.append(result)
        semaphore.release()  # Allow another task to be submitted

    pool = Pool(pool_size)

    for x in generate_args():
        semaphore.acquire()
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(x,), callback=callback)

    # Wait for all tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(len(results))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can use the following reusable classes that encapsulate the above behavior.

```py
import multiprocessing.pool
import multiprocessing
import threading

class BoundedQueuePool:
    def __init__(self, queue_size):
        self._semaphore = threading.Semaphore(queue_size)

    def _release(self, result, callback=None):
        self._semaphore.release()
        if callback:
            callback(result)

    def apply_async(self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None, error_callback=None):
        self._semaphore.acquire()
        callback_fn = self._release if callback is None else lambda result: self._release(result, callback=callback)
        error_callback_fn = self._release if error_callback is None else lambda result: self._release(result, callback=callback)
        return super().apply_async(func, args, kwds, callback=callback_fn, error_callback=error_callback_fn)

class BoundedQueueProcessPool(BoundedQueuePool, multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, *args, queue_size, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        BoundedQueuePool.__init__(self, queue_size)

class BoundedQueueThreadPool(BoundedQueuePool, multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool):
    def __init__(self, *args, queue_size, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        BoundedQueuePool.__init__(self, queue_size)


def generate_args() -> int:
    for arg in range(0, 1_000):
        yield arg

def worker(x: int) -> int:
    """Square the input."""

    return x * x

def main() -> None:
    results = []
    pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    pool = BoundedQueueProcessPool(pool_size, queue_size=2 * pool_size)

    for x in generate_args():
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(x,), callback=lambda result: results.append(result))

    # Wait for all tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(len(results))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```